# why the method doesnt work?

Tags: java, binary-tree

This method suppose to add Node to a Binary Tree.

I dont understand why it doesnt do it and where I have mistake.

root is stay on null anytime.

```
 public void add(int num)
        {
            add(num, root);
        }

        private void add(int num, Node t)
        {

            if (t == null)
                t = new Node(num);

            else if (t.getLeftSon() == null)
                t.setLeftSon(new Node (num));



 }
```

Comment: How about you take a debugger and debug it? Execute it statement by statement and compare the state with your expectations.

Comment: This question is tagged for JavaScript but your code is Java.

Comment: What precisely is the problem? Do you know _where_ it doesn't work right? How does your output differ with expected output?

Comment: hey, I am trying to run debugger..
I noticed that the root always stay "null" after every add action. 
(when it finished the root return to null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the root node is passed to the add method by value and not by reference. Java passes objects by value and not by reference. Check out the link below for further explantion
[Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Modify the add methods of your code as follows

```
public void add(int num) {
    root = add(num, root);
}

private Node add(int num, Node t) {
    if (t == null)
        return t = new Node(num);
    else if (t.getLeftSon() == null)
        t.setLeftSon(new Node(num));
    else if (t.getRightSon() == null)
        t.setRightSon(new Node(num));
    else if (Math.abs(height(t.getLeftSon()) - height(t.getRightSon())) <= 1)
        t.setLeftSon(add(num, t.getLeftSon()));
    else
         t.setRightSon(add(num, t.getRightSon()));
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another question please.. I Need to write a method that: Method receive a certain amount and returns a string that represents the nodes track the amount of which is the sum. For example, for the tree at the top, if the system will receive the sum of 16, it will return the string "9,2,5" how can I do that please ?

Comment: @zcbd You should actually ask that as another question to get sample code. But a relatively simple approach (albeit not the best) would be to traverse the tree, then store all the numbers in a linear list (like an array list), then use a double for loop to sum each of the values in the array list, storing intermediate values that make up the sum.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from:

```
private void add(int num, Node t)
{
    if (t == null)
        t = new Node(num);
    //...
 }
```

Assuming this is a method of `BTree` class and you initialise `root` to `null`, when you call:

```
add(1, root);
```

`root` won't contain the new created node when the method exits. You can do:

```
public void add(int num)
{
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(num);
    }
    else {
        add(num, root);
    }
}
```

and remove the `if (t == null)` in the `add(int num, Node t)` method.

Comment: @zcbd Question has been answered, accept the answer. If you have a new question, make a new one.